# Can I clone hardened Ubuntu app virtual servers?

Tags: networking, software-installation, 22.04, clone

We are doing a full HA system deployment of 14 CIS hardened Ubuntu 22.04LTS servers for SugarCRM V13 on-site deployment, with 2 x PHP SugarCRM web, 2 x SugarCRM API, 2 x Redis, 2 x Elastic search, 2 x GFS file, 2 x utility and  a master & slave MySQL deployment. So 7 different deployment types of server.  The Redis, Elastic & GFS servers will be configured as a Load Balanced pair, and the web & API servers will be accessed using an existing NGINX load balancer. We will be deploying this model in separate UAT, Live & DR VMware environments for a total of 42 virtual servers.

I'm being told by a specialist that it will take 20 days to build the 7 base hardened images. We then clone those images the required number of times into each environment (e.g 2  web into DR, into Live & into UAT, etc), and then each server needs to be built individually "as there is a lot of customisation required", taking an additional 46 days in total.  The specialist maintains that each application will have to be fully deployed and configured separately & it isn’t as simple as changing a few config files.  Therefore the basic server deployment will take a total of 66 days of an expensive specialist, with testing a separate line item.

Based on my reading, I’m puzzled at the level of customisation required. While I understand that, following cloning, we will need to change local network settings and reconfigure applications for the required network on each server, I think that detailed configuration of PHP/Sugarcrm, Redis, etc, will be the same on every server. Once we lay out all the IP addresses, DNS names & LB VIPs for each environment, we can put the networking details into a simple change procedure document detailing the network & application changes required for each environment. I do understand additional work will be required for the local LB configs, and for the MySQL master/slave config. My reading indicates that this again can be achieved via local config file changes. So, allowing for the 20 days to build the hardened images, I would be looking at a greatly reduced specialist requirement in deploying those images.

So my question is, in your experienced opinion, how are our servers deployed?

1. By cloning a basic hardened image for each type, and then lots of specific individual server deployment/configuration requiring a specialist?
2. By the specialist building each image fully, we then clone it repeatedly & do a step-by-step network change document, and the specialist verifies all is well?
3. Somewhere in the middle? And, if so, what servers will require customisation?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "The specialist maintains that each application will have to be fully deployed and configured separately & it isn’t as simple as changing a few config files." Not when I do it ;-) After deployment we run pre-defined scripts. I would assume 1 needs to be deployed manually and all the othere will require the same alterations but with different settings. That can be solved used `sed` instead of manually editing files

Comment: Mind that this question is not answerable. It is too specific to your situation.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. And I understand the question is specific but I'm looking for experienced opinions on how other professionals handle these deployments.